# possible/available appointments table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am building an appointments web app...the user will be able to see available/closed appointment slots for a business entity.
I am trying to use this schema  [here](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=98)

In it, there is a possible appointments table...left joining it with booked appointments table we arrive at the available appointments table.

It's structure though as depicted in the example does not reflect my needs...in my app the business entity  enters its schedule...for example:
**Monday-to-Friday 10:00AM-16:00PM...**

The question is **what structure a table must have that will hold data like this**...as I said this table will hold all possible appointment slots and its data must **be based on the schedule**...like the one above.

Answer (score 2):

Appointment scheduling is too complex for doing in SQL.  Do it in application code.

Given that, focus on having the database table(s) contain the minimal information to indicate times available and times taken.

The `SELECT` may end up being "select all rows having to do with a particular day", then the app munches on the data.